# Compution of particle size distribution by matlab img processing

Tags: matlab

I need to calculate the perimeter of some micro sized particles which are in a photo I captured.
First I Processed the image and now I want to work on 2D processed image which the particles are white and background is black as you know.
So I need some methods & codes to calculate the perimeter & diameter of particles in pixel unit. any suggestions?!
Thanks in advance

Comment: Upload some sample image(s) and link up here? Anything you have worked   upon for this? Also, look at `regionprops` for this - http://www.mathworks.in/help/images/ref/regionprops.html. It has both those features covered.

Comment: TnX for response, This is the link of photo
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=i38b5s&s=8#.UzMJmqyKHNE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code might help you understand -

```
%%// Input image
BW = imread('text.png'); %%// Available in the MATLAB image library
figure,imshow(BW)

%%// Get the scalar distances around the boundaries of the regions/blobs
P  = regionprops(BW, 'Perimeter');

%%// Get scalar values that specifies the diameter of a circle with the same
%%// area as the regions/blobs
D  = regionprops(BW, 'EquivDiameter');

%%// Get list of pixels based on their labeling. 
%%// Basically the indices of the structs produced by regionprops refer to the labels.
pixel_list = regionprops(BW, 'PixelIdxList');

%%// Let us find out information about the first blob (blob that is labeled as 1)

%%// 1. List of pixel coordinates as linear indices
blob1_pixel_list = pixel_list(1).PixelIdxList;

%%// Create an image of the same size as the original one and showing the
%%blob labeled as 1
blob1 = false(size(BW));
blob1(blob1_pixel_list) = true;
figure,imshow(blob1)

%%// Perimter of blob -1 
blob1_perimeter = P(1).Perimeter

%%// Equivalent diameter of blob -1 
blob1_equivdiameter_values = D(1).EquivDiameter

%%// Get perimeter and diameter values for all the blobs
perimeter_values = struct2array(P)
diameter_values = struct2array(D)
```

Comment: I tried them but when I use disp() to display the values,
The command line shows this: 17x1 struct array with fields:
    Perimeter

17x1 struct array with fields:
    EquivDiameter

Comment: @VahidS Check out the edited code. It gives a demo on how to get diameter and perimeter information for first blob. The first element of that 17X1 struct array is the diameter of the first blob in your case.

Comment: TNX a million it worked! , I have many questions to ask, But enough For this time. ;-)

Comment: @VahidS Look at the documentation and demos for `regionprops`. Lots of useful info there.